# Appcelerator Titanium: Create system/icon buttons without placing on toolbar

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator

Is there a way to create System buttons (or "image/icon" buttons) in Appcelerator Titanium without having to place them on a toolbar?  I would like to just be able to place them on a regular view.  As an alternative, I can just create ImageViews, but I lose the built-in animations when doing that.  I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({

   title: 'Some Title',

    top:175,

    left:5,

    width: 190,

    height: 35,

    font:{fontSize:14},

    image: 'img/some_img.png'
});`

then: 
`Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(button);`

Hope it can help !!
Cheers

Comment: What I'm actually looking for would be a button with no other visual characteristics other than the image.  Basically, exactly like a system icon button.  Just not on a toolbar.  But thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Donald, I think I can get you part of the way there, as I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem. You can eliminate the border for the button by specifying the style of the button. In the above example:

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.PLAIN
width: 35,
height: 35,
image: 'img/some_img.png' });